# vertical menu bar css

Tags: css

i would like to customize my dashboard navigation menu to vertical styling. i needed to find the `<div id="adminmenu">` but there are tons of CSS inside `/wp-admin/css`

also, does changing the CSS adminmenu is the correct approach of changing the `<ul>` into vertical styling?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't hack the Wordpress core. You can use a hook to do it. Example:

```
function dashboard_vertical_styling() {
   echo '<style type="text/css">
           #adminmenu { something goes here; }
         </style>';
}

add_action('admin_head', 'custom_colors');
```